# Default meta-data browser in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

Recently I deleted my Win XP profile that like I understand partially saved configuration of Visual Studio. When I opened my VS solution after new profile was created, I pressed F12 for see some definition of some external referenced class. IDE asked me: **"where I want to browse the source?"** Option were:

> Object Browser
>   Code Generator 
>   and something else.

Commonly I used Code Generator (the same that ALL of you using when you press **F12** on external classes), but by mistake I choose Object Browser...

How can I define back using **Code Generator**, except of deleting my profile again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have ReSharper installed. It is what did this bad things.
Solution is: Tools -> Options -> ReSharper -> Options ->Tools -> External Sources -> External Sources Data Providers -> Move down "object browser"